# How to create a LP with my own token on Jupiter? Are there LP-s on Jupiter to begin with?

Tags: spl-token, token, liquiditypool, jupiter, dex

Let's say, I've deployed a token which I want to be able to swap for SOL via a script.

There's an example of how to do it on Jupiter via flash swaps -- "Swap any token to SOL if the user has no SOL with Jupiter Flash Fill." And this is what I need.

Where will I have to create a LP of "My Token - SOL": 1) on Jupiter itself, and how? or 2) on any DEX that Jupiter works with?

Answer (score 1):

Jupiter is a Swap aggregator.

In order to deposit liquidity for your own pairs check documentation in these AMMs documentation:

Raydium.
https://raydium.io/

Orca.
https://www.orca.so/

Meteora.
https://meteora.ag/